# CreateProcessAsUser memory leak

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, windows-services

I have a service that runs the following code.
Every time that CreateProcessAsUser is hit, the memory is increased in 4K (I can see it in the Task Manager). That's not happening when I use in CreateProcess.

Why it's happening and how I can release this memory?

```
PWTS_SESSION_INFO pSessionInfo = 0;
DWORD dwCount = 0;
int dwSessionId = 0;

WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &pSessionInfo, &dwCount);
for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwCount; ++i)
{
    WTS_SESSION_INFO si = pSessionInfo[i];
    if (WTSActive == si.State)
    {
        dwSessionId = si.SessionId;
        break;
    }
}
WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);

HANDLE currentToken;
BOOL bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, &currentToken);
if (bRet == false)
{
    return 0;
}

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
if (CreateProcessAsUser(currentToken, "MY_EXE.exe", "MY_ARGS_STR", NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    if (pi.hProcess != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
    if (pi.hThread != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}
CloseHandle(currentToken);

return 0;
```

Comment: You probably don't have a real memory leak. Task Manager is not a tool for detecting memory leaks.

Comment: So, if you run this in a loop 1000 times, you get 4MB more memory? Or is it just the one extra 4KB? It's entirely possible that somewhere in a corner of your process, the kernel stashes away some information needed by your process to control the other user's process. And that extra info isn't needed by CreateProcess. Unless you really do get 4MB if you do this 1000 times [you may try 10 first...]

Comment: You were right. The increasing of 4K occurs only twice so it's not a memory leak and it's not something that I need to free. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no problem :)